# Searching for a character in the bash prompt

Tags: bash, command-line, shortcut

In vim, to find a character you can use 'f' to find the next matching character in the line that your cursor is on, and 'F' to find the previous matching character in the line that your cursor is on.

Is there a way to move around like that on the bash command line?

I know that you can set bash to be in vim mode, by saying `set -o vim`, and this works great for my local machine, but I administer a lot of machines where I can't change that setting.

Comment: If you administer the machines, why can't you add `set editing-mode vi` to `~/.inputrc`? Simply because there are a lot of them and it would be a pain, or something else?

Comment: I definitely could, but my coworkers dislike vim so I have been overruled on doing that.  We have to log onto the machines as the same user so any configuration changes I make to the environment for myself will affect them as well (and I don't have controller over the single-user thing unfortunately.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring for a moment the security issues associated with everybody in your office sharing the same user, you could add a key binding to the [readline command](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC21) `character-search`:

```
# ~/.inputrc
C-]: character-search
```

To use the search, type `Ctrl-]` followed by the character you want to search for. You can bind the command to any key sequence, not just `Ctrl-]`, but for obvious reasons you probably don't want to emulate `vi` mode by binding it to the letter `f`.

This would be less invasive than turning on `vi` mode so most users would probably not even notice the change. However, somebody could easily stumble upon your key sequence by accident and become very confused. You would also have to use three keystrokes instead of the two you're accustomed to with `vi`.

Comment: Thanks! and I agree with you about the same user thing

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-character_002dsearch-_0028C_002d_005d_0029), `character-search` is by default bound to `C-]`, and `character-search-backward` to `M-C-]`, so you don't have to bind them manually.

Note that these commands take a numerical argument, so to skip e.g. to the fifth next occurrence of the letter `o`, type `M-5 C-] o`, or `ESC 5 C-] o`.